# Есть ли более короткий способ задавать параметры в PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Есть ли более простой и короткий способ задать параметры в PDO? Как вы обычно это делаете?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $response['values']['value1']);
            $stmt->bindValue(2, $response['values']['value2']);
            $stmt->bindValue(3, $value3);
            $stmt->bindValue(4, $response['values']['value3']);
            $stmt->bindValue(5, $response['values']['value4']);
            $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php) вроде крайне доходчиво в примерах показано как можно передавать параметры,

Comment: Обычно "мы" не работаем с `PDO` в чистом виде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO table (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$roms = $pdo->prepare($stmt)->execute([
$response['values']['value1'],
$response['values']['value2'],
$response['values']['value3'],
$response['values']['value4'],
$response['values']['value5']]);
```